# Converting an array received via POST into new array

Tags: php, arrays, json, forms, post

I am sending an array through POST via a hidden input on a form.  I am using JSON to populate the value of this hidden field with the array that I need to pass.  On the form handler I then receive the array. However, when I try to count the number of items on the received array it says it is one.  It seems that when I $_POST the received variable has the format of an array ["...","..."] but it not recognized as one.  Can I cast it into an array?  I used the explode() with the comma delimited but the exploded array maintains the '[' and ']' with the first and last elements of the array.

HTML: (here I am showing an example with the value field already populated)

```
<input type="hidden" name="uploadFilenames" id="uploadFilenames" value="["64034_397137903702241_1591760198_n.jpg","77089_399984063417625_1968141154_n.jpg"]">
```

PHP:

```
$filearray =    $_POST['uploadFilenames'];
$numFiles = count($filearray); 
for($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; $i++) {
    echo $filearray[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: json_decode\encode or serialize\unserialize

Comment: *serialize/unserialize @Dagon :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse JSON via PHP you will need to use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

`$filearray = json_decode($filearray);`